# Pass variables between stages in azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to setup a pipeline for my project to create a prerelease and automatically deploy it to a CDN. The CDN deployment is a separate template that we reuse, and expects some parameters like `packageVersion`. I'd like to automatically pick up the `packageVersion` in an earlier stage and pass it to the CDN deployment template, so we dont have to do any manual steps.

My pipeline looks as follows:

```yaml
stages:
  # Run build stage on Azure Agent
  - stage: Build
    dependsOn:
      - ResolveDependenciesNPM
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        steps:
          # tasks for npm install etc

          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: 'Update pkgversion variable'
            name: packageversion
            inputs:
              script: |
                PACKAGE_VERSION=$(node -p -e "require('./package.json').version")
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pkgversion;isOutput=true]$PACKAGE_VERSION"
                cat package.json
                echo ""
                echo "[PRERELEASE VERSION]:"
                echo "$PACKAGE_VERSION"
                echo ""

          # tasks for code validation, publish, bundle, etc

  - template: path/to/deploy/template.yml@global-templates
    parameters:
      dependsOn: 
        - Build
      template: global-templates
      packageVersion: "$[stageDependencies.Build.Build.outputs['packageversion.pkgversion']]"
      # also tried:
      # packageVersion: ${{ pkgversion }}
      # packageVersion: ${{ variables.pkgversion }}
      # packageVersion: $(pkgversion)
      # packageVersion: $(variables.pkgversion)
```

But I can't seem to find the right way to get the `pkgversion` variable to evaluate correctly when I pass it as a parameter. How can I pass the `pkgversion` variable to the CDN deploy template as a parameter?

Comment: Can you show your ` path/to/deploy/template.yml@global-templates`? It could depend where do you use `packageVersion` on stage or job level? On condition etc?

Comment: It could be a problem with your expression, or it could be that stage parameters don't support expressions like that. Worth finding out which, by adding a non-template stage with a variable which uses that expression, to see if the expression can be evaluated OK in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Try a "trick" that worked for me:

1. declare **the second stage in the same file** (you will pass only job(s) as template)
2. add variable to the second stage, e.g

   ```
   variables:
      packageVersionVar: "$[stageDependencies.Build.Build.outputs['packageversion.pkgversion']]"
   ```
3. pass variable `$(packageVersionVar)` as a value to your packageVersion parameter